# How to add leading zeros to select rows in a data frame column using dplyr pipes

Tags: r, dplyr, pipeline

Consider `data` created here:

```r
data <- data.frame(ID = sample(10000,100), not.imp1 = rnorm(100), not.imp2 = rnorm(100), not.imp3 = rnorm(100))
#Note that not all IDs are the same length
```

We have data for 100 `ID`s, where each individual has a unique `ID` number. Columns `not.imp1:3` are only relevant to show the structure of the dataframe.
We want to add a leading zero to the first 95 `ID` numbers. I am trying to do this using `dplyr` pipes, but cant figure out how to add the zeros.
Here is how I subset the data that I want to add the zeros to:

```r
library(dplyr)
data%>%
select(ID)%>%
slice(1:95)
```

I have tried several things like adding `%>%mutate(paste0("0",.))` to the pipe, but havent gotten anything to work. what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach

```
data2 <- data %>% 
  mutate(ID = ifelse(row_number()<= 95, paste0("0", ID), ID))

head(data2)
#     ID   not.imp1   not.imp2   not.imp3
# 1 09449 -1.4297317 -2.2210106  0.1923912
# 2 07423  1.9010681  1.0825734 -0.8855694
# 3 06283  0.2508254 -0.5307967  2.1645044
# 4 05593 -2.2451267  0.1281156 -1.8528800
# 5 09194 -0.1677409 -0.7422480 -0.4237452
# 6 07270 -0.2536918  1.2289698  1.0083092
tail(data2)
#       ID   not.imp1   not.imp2   not.imp3
# 95  06538  1.0071791  0.1596557 -0.7099883
# 96   4829  0.2444440  0.8869954 -1.2938356
# 97   2571 -1.1012023  0.8343393 -0.6264487
# 98    150  0.2116460 -0.2146265 -1.8281045
# 99   3107 -1.2379193  0.3491078  1.4531531
# 100  9953 -0.9326725  1.1146032 -1.5542687
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sprintf()` to pad to 3 digits:

`data %>% mutate(ID = sprintf("%03d", ID))`

You can change `%03d` to change how many leading zeros to add. Eg. `%05d` will ensure all IDs are at least 5 digits long.

Answer (score 1):

Use of str_pad is helpful

```
data <- data.frame(ID = sample(10000,100), not.imp1 = rnorm(100), not.imp2 = rnorm(100), not.imp3 = rnorm(100)) %>% 
  mutate(ID = str_pad(string = ID, width = 4, side = 'left', pad = 0))
```

[image: dataframe]

Answer (score 0):

This would be a quick and easy way to do it. I didn't use `dplyr` or `pipeing`, but you could merge this idea with the code you already tried if you want to.

```
data[which(nchar(data[,"ID"])==3),"ID"]<-paste0(0,data[which(nchar(data[,"ID"])==3),"ID"])
data[which(nchar(data[,"ID"])==2),"ID"]<-paste0(00,data[which(nchar(data[,"ID"])==2),"ID"])
```